# How to create a prism effect on image hover

Tags: javascript, css, image, hover, effect

I wanted to re-create an effect similar to this one here:

[image: here].

Source: [prys.me](http://prys.me/projets)

I'm not sure how I would go about replicating in JS or whether it would be possible using CSS only as I'm pretty new to js.

Thank you :)

Comment: I am wondering if that is even possible with JS

Comment: @FlyingGambit It most definitely is possible with JS. Distortion: [prism effect](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/03/31/prism-effect-slider-canvas/) and color: [texteffects](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/texteffects/).

Comment: @EmilS.Jørgensen Thats awesome, thanks for the links